# Half multiple newlines

Tags: php, newline

This is kind of a silly question and really just for personal interests more than anything,
but how would you go about halving multiple newlines?

So lets say I have a series of two \r\n (carriage return/newlines) as a constant, so

```
Class FOO
{
    Const DELIM = "\r\n\r\n";

    private fullDelim, halfDelim = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fullDelim = self::DELIM;
        $this->halfDelim = substr(self::DELIM, -(count(self::DELIM)/2); // or something ??
    }
}
```

Would that be a sane thing to do? can you even substr on newlines? I'm very curious on how you'd go about this in a "sane" way?

Comment: what do you mean by "halving a newline"?

Comment: I would just define another `Const`:  `Const DELIM_HALF = "\r\n";`

Comment: He means cut the DELIM string in half; take "\r\n\r\n" and turn it into "\r\n". Not sure why..

Comment: @antiduh Honestly just for personal interests, there's no real reason to do this, I just thought about how I would do it when I was constructing a class since I do not believe you can use `count()` on them? I guess you can use `substr_count()` or `preg_match_all()` though corr?

Comment: `Count` counts the number of distinct elements in an array. If the DELIM is a string, then count will *probably* return '1', since there's only one element to speak of (there's no array..). PHP might be weird and treat the string as an array of characters, in which case count would work (tells you the number of elements in the array..). However, all of that doesn't matter - PHP has a strlen function for telling you the exact length of a string, just use that. Furthermore, whether or not these are newlines or anything else doesn't matter. Characters are characters.

Comment: Plus one, great explanation. `strlen()` would be a great way to do this too =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strlen()` to get the length of a string, not `count()`.

```
$this->halfDelim = substr(self::DELIM, -(strlen(self::DELIM)/2);
```

Comment: Accepted. same thing we where talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this works, I'm actually a bit surprised....

```
$half substr(self::DELIM, -(preg_match_all ('/\r\n/', self::DELIM)/2));
```

Test

```
echo preg_match_all ('/\r\n/', self::DELIM);  // 2
echo count(substr(self::DELIM, -(preg_match_all ('/\r\n/', self::DELIM)/2))); // 1
```